# WIX Installer (.MSI) failing due to WebView2 runtime installer registry check

Tags: wix, webview2

We are using **Package bootstrapper as binary stream** to use during app install to do the WebView2 runtime installer registry check.
but our installer fails with the below error and installation is not happening.

The machine we tried to install already has webview2 runtime installed

**Image 1:** [image]
**Image 2:**
[image]

we are following the below steps in our product.wxs file.

**Step 1 :**

```
<Property Id="WVRTINSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled1" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" />
  <RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled2" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" />
  <RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled3" Root="HKCU" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" />
</Property>
<Binary Id="MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe" SourceFile="C:\Users\source\setup dependency\MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe"/>
<CustomAction Id='InvokeBootstrapper' BinaryKey='MicrosoftEdgeWebview2Setup.exe' Execute="deferred" ExeCommand=' /install' Return='check' />
```

**Step 2 :**

```
<Custom Action="CloseAppsPrompt" After="CostFinalize"></Custom>
<Custom Action='InvokeBootstrapper' Before='InstallFinalize'>
<![CDATA[NOT(REMOVE OR WVRTINSTALLED)]]>
</Custom>
```

**Note :** We have followed the steps given in this sample : https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/main/SampleApps/WV2DeploymentWiXCustomActionSample/Product.wxs

I am trying to check multiple registry for webview2 and I expect to install if it is not available already in any of the registries of the user machine and skip the installation if it is already present in the user machine

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but I can't simply comment on your post because I don't have enough reputation points. But I'd like to suggest something in case it helps get you past your problem.

I am installing Webview2 in one of my installers and checking the same registry entry as your WVRTInstalled2 reference. My suggestion is to find which of those is actually set (perhaps WVRTInstalled2, as is the case with mine), and include only that RegistrySearch to set your property. If that sets the WVRTINSTALLED property correctly, then perhaps the inclusion of the other 2 is creating an "AND" condition rather than an "OR" condition.

If you're never able to solve the setting of WVRTINSTALLED, then I suggest changing the execution of the Webview2 installer to silent, so all of that is handled quickly and without user intervention.

Sorry if that isn't as helpful as you need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use should use RegistrySearch separately:

```
<Property Id="WVRTINSTALLED_64">
  <RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled64" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" Win64="yes"/>
</Property>

<Property Id="WVRTINSTALLED_32">
  <RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled32" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" Win64="no"/>
</Property>

<Property Id="WVRTINSTALLED_32_USER">
  <RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled32User" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" Win64="no"/>
</Property>
```

And use conditions like this:

```
<![CDATA[NOT (REMOVE OR WVRTINSTALLED_64 OR WVRTINSTALLED_32 OR WVRTINSTALLED_32_USER)]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides other suggestions I noticed that you are simply omiting one backslash in the registry key path. You wrote:

```
<RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled1" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" />
```

And it should be:

```
<RegistrySearch Id="WVRTInstalled1" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}" Name="pv" Type="raw" />
```

etc.